# Expectation (covariance) between $X_j$ and $Y$ in logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic, covariance

Is there some way to explore the relationship of $E(X_jY)$ in a logistic regression?
That is, $Y$ is a binary variable observed together with $p$-covariates $X$ (wlog centered). I am interested in calculating $E(X_jY) = {\rm Cov}(X_j,Y)$ for the $j$-th regressor but am helpless.

We have $Y|X \sim {\rm Ber}(p(X))$ where $p(X) = \exp(\beta'X)/(1+\exp(\beta'X))$.
Is there any way to calculate $E(X_jY)$?

Comment: It might help to observe that $\text{Cov}(X_j,Y)$ is not, in general, equal to the expectation of $X_jY$.  Whether your question (in either form--as an expectation or a covariance) has any simple answer depends on your assumption about the distribution of $X$.

Comment: can't edit my last post anymore. something was missing:
$X_j$ is centered so $COV(X_j,Y) = E(X_jY)$. In my case, the covariance of $X$ is known by assumption. I would like to simplify $E(X_jY)$ somehow in terms of this covariance/moments. 
For example in a linear regression $Y = \sum_j \beta_j X_j + \varepsilon$ we would have 
$$E(X_lY) = \sum_j \beta_j cov(X_j,X_l) $$
I would love to derive something like this, when the underlying model is assumed to be a logistic regression model.